How can I identify and delete dead code in Xcode Swift
Is there a way to get Xcode to show a warning/error for unused functions and properties?
I have some dead dummy code left over from refactoring but no way to easily identify and delete it.
I'm in a corporate setting with no access to 3rd party libs. I'm interested in a .swiftlint or native approach employing a build phase script in Xcode

You should be more specific about what you are trying to identify.
⚠️ First-Party Tools - Very Limited for Swift
Xcode has a few built-in tools that can help. You have likely seen some of these already:

Xcode and SPM try to strip out dead code from the final binary by default, though it seems not to be working correctly and is stated as a bug.

Also, as an Apple Engineer stated offering ways to check it yourself:

Any types unused by your actual application code are removed by the compiler

However, these tools may not cover all your needs, such as identifying unused properties and functions, and were not designed to assist in the refactoring process.
Generally, most native tools inside the Xcode's Build Settings are for the C family, and there is limited support for Swift. You can browse through all the available options like this.

✅ Third-Party Tools - Way More Coverage (Especially for Swift)
Several third-party tools are available to help identify unused code in your Swift projects.
One of the most well-known open-source tools is Periphery.
It can analyze function parameters, protocols, enumerations, assign-only properties, redundant public accessibility, unused imports, Objective-C, Codable, XCTestCase, Interface Builder, and more; offering even more than just analysis!
Instead of repeating its documentation here, I'll just say that it is very easy to use and incredibly powerful.
Hope this helps!

This is cool but I'm in a corporate setting with no access to 3rd party libs. I'm interested in a .swiftlint or native approach employing a build phase script in Xcode

Each part of the code has a different method to be identified as dead. Investigating open-source projects can help you achieve what you are looking for.

Also, Xcode has many tools for this natively. I have updated my answer for more information about that as well.

@etayluz There is no built-in way to learn automatically that code is unused - for example, that a class is defined but never instantiated (a common problem with a large long-lived codebase that has been through many hands). If you can't accept the notion of using a third-party tool to help with this, then the answer is that you just have to use your brain (and luck) to find the unused code. Besides, swift lint is third-party and you don't object to that.

@MojtabaHosseini I've experimented setting all of those "Unused" settings to "YES" but I still don't see any warnings in XCode. I'm afraid matt is right :( Can you show a working example with "First Party Tools" of an unused variable and prove matt wrong please?

The "Apple Clang" settings are for C-type languages only which doesn't include Swift. The Swift compiler itself only has warnings for local variables declaration (as shown in the screenshots) being unused and they are enabled by default. Periphery is definitely the best suggestion here. However, given that you seem to use SwiftLint already, it just learned a new rule triggering on unused parameters. It's not yet released, but a new version is in the making.

The question is about Swift. This answer claims that the Clang settings will work for Swift, and that is just plain false.
